# Bash- Running aws ec2 run-instances in background

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

How can i run the command `aws ec2 run-instances` in bash (mac os) so it will run in the background? (Right now when i run it it is in interactive mode in which i need to scroll until the end)

Comment: Do you mean, you just want to read the output of the command when it is done?

Comment: No i don't need to read any output. I simply want to run aws ec2 run-instances and run another command right after it.

Comment: This link might help you:- [How to Run Linux Commands in Background](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-run-linux-commands-in-background/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That command actually executes and completes immediately.

However, the AWS CLI is using a **pager** to show you the output. You can modify this behaviour by either requesting less information to be returned by using `--query`, or by **removing the pager**.

To remove the pager, add this to your `~/.aws/config` file:

```
[default]
cli_pager=
```

This will cause all output to scroll up the screen without waiting for user input.

For more details, see: [Using AWS CLI pagination options - AWS Command Line Interface](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-pagination.html#cli-usage-pagination-clientside)

Comment: Thanks. So if i have in the bash script a command right after this command will the 2nd command run right away or is it waiting for user input?

Comment: Also, are there any other ways to remove the pager?

Comment: It only 'waits' for input if the displayed information is too large for one screen. As per the linked documentation, another option is to specify `--no-cli-pager` on the command.